# How to add a fade function to an existing slideshow script element

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, fadeout

I have the following script which initiates a slideshow on my website danmccready.com/Aviemore The problem that I am having is that the slides do change every 3 seconds but I want them to change with a gradual fading effect.  I have changed the crossFadeDuration variable with no joy. Any ideas, Thanks Dan

```
 // set the following variables
 // Set slideShowSpeed (milliseconds)
 var slideShowSpeed = 3000

 // Duration of crossfade (seconds)
 var crossFadeDuration = 1000


 // Specify the image files
 var Pic = new Array() // don't touch this
 // to add more images, just continue
 // the pattern, adding to the array below
 Pic[0] = 'image1.jpg'

 }

 function runSlideShow(){
     if (document.all){
        document.images.SlideShow.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=2)"
        document.images.SlideShow.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=crossFadeDuration=1000)"
        document.images.SlideShow.filters.blendTrans.Apply()      
     }
     document.images.SlideShow.src = preLoad[j].src
     if (document.all){
         document.images.SlideShow.filters.blendTrans.Play()
     }
     j = j + 1
     if (j > (p-1)) j=0
         t = setTimeout('runSlideShow()', slideShowSpeed)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going the javascript way, u can use the jquery plugin . Things become much easier then. I have fiddled a small Example . Have a look at , might help you : http://jsfiddle.net/YueA6/

The jquery method :

```
fadeOut()
```

can be used here to great effect.